# aspectj-maven-plugin error: type already defined

Tags: maven, aspectj, amazon-swf, aspectj-maven-plugin

I'm trying to use AspectJ with Maven for Amazon SWF. I've added the plugins to generate client code and to weave aspects. I've also added the `maven-compiler-plugin` to disable annotation processing.
 When I run `mvn compile` I see that the client code is generated in `target/generated-sources/annotation`. But it also throws the following error. I've also included the `pom.xml` file here.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building read-book 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- apt-maven-plugin:1.1.3:process (default) @ read-book ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ read-book ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ read-book ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 13 source files to /Users/cnadig-cc/read-book/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.4:compile (default) @ read-book ---
[WARNING] AsynchronyDeciderAnnotationProcessor.process() invoked.
[WARNING] Processing @Workflow for ReadBookWorkflow
[WARNING] AsynchronyDeciderAnnotationProcessor.process() invoked.
[WARNING] Processing finished
[ERROR] The type ReadBookWorkflowClient is already defined
[ERROR] The type ReadBookWorkflowClientImpl is already defined
[ERROR] The type ReadBookWorkflowClientFactory is already defined
[ERROR] The type ReadBookWorkflowClientFactoryImpl is already defined
[ERROR] The type ReadBookWorkflowClientExternal is already defined
[ERROR] The type ReadBookWorkflowClientExternalImpl is already defined
[ERROR] The type ReadBookWorkflowClientExternalFactory is already defined
[ERROR] The type ReadBookWorkflowClientExternalFactoryImpl is already defined
[ERROR] The type ReadBookWorkflowSelfClient is already defined
[ERROR] The type ReadBookWorkflowSelfClientImpl is already defined
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.475 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-15T17:22:00-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/384M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.4:compile (default) on project read-book: Compiler errors:
[ERROR] error at public interface ReadBookWorkflowClient extends WorkflowClient
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] /Users/cnadig-cc/read-book/read/book/ReadBookWorkflowClient.java:21:0::0 The type ReadBookWorkflowClient is already defined
[ERROR] error at class ReadBookWorkflowClientImpl extends WorkflowClientBase implements ReadBookWorkflowClient {
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] /Users/cnadig-cc/read-book/read/book/ReadBookWorkflowClientImpl.java:18:0::0 The type ReadBookWorkflowClientImpl is already defined
[ERROR] error at public interface ReadBookWorkflowClientFactory extends WorkflowClientFactory<ReadBookWorkflowClient> {
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] /Users/cnadig-cc/read-book/read/book/ReadBookWorkflowClientFactory.java:18:0::0 The type ReadBookWorkflowClientFactory is already defined
[ERROR] error at public class ReadBookWorkflowClientFactoryImpl extends WorkflowClientFactoryBase<ReadBookWorkflowClient> implements ReadBookWorkflowClientFactory {
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] /Users/cnadig-cc/read-book/read/book/ReadBookWorkflowClientFactoryImpl.java:17:0::0 The type ReadBookWorkflowClientFactoryImpl is already defined
[ERROR] error at public interface ReadBookWorkflowClientExternal extends WorkflowClientExternal
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] /Users/cnadig-cc/read-book/read/book/ReadBookWorkflowClientExternal.java:20:0::0 The type ReadBookWorkflowClientExternal is already defined
[ERROR] error at class ReadBookWorkflowClientExternalImpl extends WorkflowClientExternalBase implements ReadBookWorkflowClientExternal {
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] /Users/cnadig-cc/read-book/read/book/ReadBookWorkflowClientExternalImpl.java:17:0::0 The type ReadBookWorkflowClientExternalImpl is already defined
[ERROR] error at public interface ReadBookWorkflowClientExternalFactory extends WorkflowClientFactoryExternal<ReadBookWorkflowClientExternal> {
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] /Users/cnadig-cc/read-book/read/book/ReadBookWorkflowClientExternalFactory.java:18:0::0 The type ReadBookWorkflowClientExternalFactory is already defined
[ERROR] error at public class ReadBookWorkflowClientExternalFactoryImpl extends WorkflowClientFactoryExternalBase<ReadBookWorkflowClientExternal>  implements ReadBookWorkflowClientExternalFactory {
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] /Users/cnadig-cc/read-book/read/book/ReadBookWorkflowClientExternalFactoryImpl.java:18:0::0 The type ReadBookWorkflowClientExternalFactoryImpl is already defined
[ERROR] error at public interface ReadBookWorkflowSelfClient extends WorkflowSelfClient
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] /Users/cnadig-cc/read-book/read/book/ReadBookWorkflowSelfClient.java:19:0::0 The type ReadBookWorkflowSelfClient is already defined
[ERROR] error at public class ReadBookWorkflowSelfClientImpl extends WorkflowSelfClientBase implements ReadBookWorkflowSelfClient {
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] /Users/cnadig-cc/read-book/read/book/ReadBookWorkflowSelfClientImpl.java:18:0::0 The type ReadBookWorkflowSelfClientImpl is already defined
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException`enter code here`
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>read-book</groupId>
    <artifactId>read-book</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <aspectjrt.version>1.8.2</aspectjrt.version>
        <aws.version>1.10.17</aws.version>
        <freemarker.version>2.3.23</freemarker.version>
        <aspectj-maven-plugin.version>1.4</aspectj-maven-plugin.version>
        <aspectj-runtime.version>1.8.2</aspectj-runtime.version>
        <compliance.level>1.8</compliance.level>
        <target.dir>target</target.dir>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectjrt.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${target.dir}/generated-sources/annotations</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.amazonaws.eclipse.simpleworkflow.asynchrony.annotationprocessor.AsynchronyDeciderAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.18</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aws.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
                        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
                        <version>${freemarker.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                        <version>3.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <!-- This disables annotation processing in the compiling phase -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                    <source>${compliance.level}</source>
                    <target>${compliance.level}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- This does the actual weaving of aspects -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- include this in order to keep aspectjrt consistent across all dependencies -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj-runtime.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>${compliance.level}</complianceLevel>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>${compliance.level}</source>
                    <target>${compliance.level}</target>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <!-- include this to ensure @Asynchronous and @ExponentialRetry annotations work -->
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                    <sources>
                        <source>
                            <basedir>${target.dir}/generated-sources/annotations</basedir>
                        </source>
                        <source>
                            <basedir>src/main/java</basedir>
                        </source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal> <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
                            <goal>test-compile</goal> <!-- use this goal to weave all your test classes -->
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Why do you use an ancient version of [aspectj-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/) ?

Answer (score 1):

With the later releases of the swf build tools jar, if you are using maven compiler plugin and have the build tools jar on your class path it automatically tries to generate the client code. 
So you don't need to define any annotation processing specially in your Pom.

Comment: Does that include the Aspectj processing on @Asynchronous methods? There is a specific cut and join point there